# Let $\text{x}:U→S$ and $\text{x}:U→\bar{S}$ be parametrizations such that $E=λ^2\bar{E}$, $F=λ^2\bar{F}$, $G=λ^2\bar{G}$ in $U$...

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $\text{x}:U→S$ and $\text{x}:U→\bar{S}$ be parametrizations such that $E=λ^2\bar{E}$, $F=λ^2\bar{F}$, $G=λ^2\bar{G}$ in $U$, where $λ^2$ is a nowhere-zero differentiable function in $U$. Then the map $\varphi = \bar{\text{x}} ◦ \text{x}^{1} : \text{x}(U)→\bar{S}$ is a local conformal map.

**Attempt:**

Let $p∈\text{x}(U)$ and $w∈T_p(S)$. Then $w$ is tangent to a curve $x(α(t))$ at $t=0$ where $α(t)=(u(t),\, v(t))$ is a curve in $U$; thus, $w$ may be written ($t=0$) $$w=\text{x}_uu'+\text{x}_vv'.$$ By deﬁnition, the vector $d\varphi_p(w)$ is the tangent vector to the curve
$\text{x}◦\text{x}^{-1}◦\text{x}(α(t))$, i.e., to the curve $\bar{\text{x}}(α(t))$ at $t=0$. Thus, $$d\varphi_p(w)= \bar{\text{x}}_uu′+\bar{\text{x}}_vv′.$$ Since

\begin{align*} 
I_p(w) &= E(u')^2+2Fu'v'+G(v')^2, \\ 
I_{\varphi (p)}(d\varphi_p(w)) &= \bar{E}(u')^2+2\bar{F}u'v'+\bar{G}(v')^2,
\end{align*}

we conclude that $I_p(w)=I_{\varphi (p)}(d\varphi_p(w))$ for all $p\in \text{x}(U)$ and all $w\in T_p(S)$; hence, $\varphi$ is a local conformal map.

[image]

Comment: Didn't you lose $\lambda^2$? What is the definition of conformal you are using? Ordinarily, it involves angles, but you may have a different definition.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have already placed the definition